# Equation of Logarithmical Spiral

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

A straight line OL rotates around the point O with a constant angular velocity !. A point M moves along the line OL with a speed proportional to the distance OM. Find the equation of the curve described by the point M

As it says angular velocity is constant which i think means 
                            $$θ' =constant=ω$$

and after integrating i get $$θ = ω ⋅ t + θ_o$$

What can i do about the linear velocity?

Can someone help me with this problem

Comment: $r'=kr$ means $r=e^{kt}$.

Comment: @Aretino I do not understand how you get an exponential function after integration.

Comment: @Aretino Can you please explain how you get this relation $$r'=kr$$ ?

Comment: $r=OM$, $v=r'$.

Comment: @Aretino Can you please give the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a constant ratio between any two velocities. There are several ways to say the same thing.

$$\frac { r \,d \theta}{ dr}  = \frac { r \,d \theta/dt}{ dr/dt} =\frac { V_{\theta}}{ V_{r}}= \tan \psi =  const. \tag{1} $$

Log variation ( instead of $ \cot \psi$ say $k$ )

$$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=kr\tag{2}$$

$$r= a e^{k \theta }\tag{3}$$

where $a$ is arbitrary

Linear variation

$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\omega \tag{4}$$

$$ \theta = \omega t + \alpha \tag{5}$$

where $\alpha$  is arbitrary

Plug into (2)

$$r=ae^{k (\omega t + \alpha )}\tag{6}$$

Comment: Which one is the correct answer?

Comment: That you have to decide yourself. I clarified that ratio between any two of  three ( radial, circumferential or along arc ) velocities is same.

Comment: I do not know that is why I asked....

Comment: The answers are equivalent. The $\alpha$ in the equation from @Narasimham is subsumed in the constant $C$ of my equation.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$\frac{dr}{dt}=kr\tag{1}$$

There is a [long way](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx) to determine that this means $$r=Ce^{kt}\tag{2}$$

or there is the shorter way of simply inserting answer $2$ into the differential equation $1$ and seeing that it works.

We also know that $$\theta = \omega t\tag{3}$$

Isolating $t$ from equation $3$ and inserting in equation $2$ we get  $$r=Ce^{\frac{k}{\omega}\theta}$$

or the equation of a [logarithmic spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral).

Comment: can you please explain how you get (1)

Comment: From " A point M moves along the line OL with a speed proportional to the distance OM". I.e. the radial speed of $M$ is proportional to its current radius.

Comment: can i use $$θ=ω⋅t+θ_o$$ => $$(θ-θo)/ω=t$$ in place of $$θ=ω⋅t$$ ??

Comment: Certainly. Any constant in the exponent of $e$ will just be incorporated as part of the constant $C$. Remember, $e^{a+b} = e^{a}*e^{b}$.

Comment: so the equation becomes $$r=C . exp[(k/ω)(θ-θ_o)]$$ right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate your help.